# Cloud solution with key value storage and user authentication for iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, cloud

Say I have a game/app for both android, iOS and web and I need to store some info to be available for the user across devices.

So basically I would like to use a service with following features (in prioritized order)

- hosting and mainentance covered
- API for persisting and retreiving data
- key value storage
- SDK for android and iOS
- user authentication

Simplified: I want to know which services I can use which let's me code apps with user data persistence and not think about server-code at all.

I have no knowledge of solutions like this. Maybe amazon or google has solutions like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice overview can be found here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more

Answer (score 0):

*Parse* seems to somehow solve most of my needs

https://parse.com/products/data